# react native Tappable links (hyperlinks / mailto) inside text View

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperlink, mobile-application

How to implement a component so that when I pass text to it.
All the hyperlinks `(https://somelink.com)` in the text should become tappable.
All the emails`(example@example.com)` in the text should open the default mail app on the device

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a ready-to-go implementation, you could use [`react-string-replace`](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace) following the [`Multiple replacements on a single string`](https://github.com/iansinnott/react-string-replace#multiple-replacements-on-a-single-string) section of the docs:

```
const text = 'Hey @ian_sinn, check out this link https://github.com/iansinnott/ Hope to see you at #reactconf';
let replacedText;

// Match URLs
replacedText = reactStringReplace(text, /(https?:\/\/\S+)/g, (match, i) => (
  <a key={match + i} href={match}>{match}</a>
));

// Match @-mentions
replacedText = reactStringReplace(replacedText, /@(\w+)/g, (match, i) => (
  <a key={match + i} href={`https://twitter.com/${match}`}>@{match}</a>
));
```

Adjust the regexes used and components rendered to match your use case.